# Assign red channel from one PNG as the Alpha using montage

Tags: imagemagick

I have two images and I want to use the Red Channel from the mask.png and use it as the alpha of the beauty.png, saving the composite out as a new file called final.png

I noticed the file generated does not look correct and is super small for some reason as well. I would like it to be the same size as the source files, which are both the same size.

```
'C:/helpers/montage.exe convert C:/temp/teapot_beauty.png C:/temp/teapot_mask.png -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite C:/temp/final.png'
```

[image]

[image]

My current output looks nothing like what I have show below.
The goal is to have it output the final image containing an alpha.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using montage.exe convert, which is totally wrong. It should simply be magick.exe.

```
magick.exe teapot.png ( redpot.png -channel r -separate +channel ) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please consider using `PIL` package instead. It's designed specifically for working with images. Something like this should solve your particular task:

```py
from PIL import Image

kettle = Image.open('./kettle_images/kettle.png')
mask = Image.open('./kettle_images/mask.png')
kettle.putalpha(mask.getchannel('R'))
kettle.save('./kettle_images/final.png')
```

Comment: in my case i need it to be done using montage as PIL is not something i'll have access to. Only ImageMagik's montage or ffmpeg

Comment: well it's not really a python problem then, you're only using python to do `Popen`, this should be a bash script IMHO

Comment: well regardless of that, the code above commandline is not working. that is the main problem